# Loop through worksheets without using VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I need to total certain cells based on a condition across all worksheets in the workbook.

The pseudocode would be

```
Foreach ws as Worksheet
    'total =SUMIF (A2:A5, "search term", B2:B5)
Next
MsgBox (total)
```

But I don't want to use a macro.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a fixed number of worksheets?

Comment: I think I'm right in saying that Excel questions *not* involving VBA are better suited for superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

You can do a 3D-reference (across multiple sheets), but only with SUM not with SUMIF.

You could put the SUMIF bit into a new column in each sheet, and then SUM the results of these with a 3D-reference.